# CPAN module prereqs

Tags: perl, cpan

I plan on uploading a module to CPAN, shortly. This is the first module I've contributed. I've got the module to what I'd consider a "beta" stage. I'm using ExtUtils::MakeMaker to generate a Makefile through Makefile.PL (I've pasted the contents of it below). The Makefile.PL script has all the prereq modules listed. I'm wondering at which point in the installation process, the prereq modules are installed if they're not present? I'm wondering because I ran Makefile.PL followed by `make` then `make install` in a separate environment that's missing some of the prereq modules. However, they were not installed? I was under the impression they would be but maybe im missing something? I'm looking for someone to provide some clarity. Thanks in advance~

Makefile.PL

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    NAME      => 'Imgur',
    VERSION   => '0.01',
    PREREQ_PM => {
        'JSON'                      => 2.90,
        'LWP::UserAgent'            => 6.05,
        'HTTP::Request::Common'     => 6.04,
        'Data::Dumper'              => 2.154,
        'DateTime::Format::ISO8601' => 0.08,
        'Config::IniFiles'          => 2.86,
        'Scalar::Util'              => 1.42,
        'Class::Std::Utils'         => 0.0.3,
        'MIME::Base64'              => 3.15,
        'File::Slurp'               => 9999.19
    }
);
```

Comment: On a side note, you should specify the versions as strings (e.g. `'JSON' => '2.90',`).  This avoids floating point conversion issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Makefile.PL doesn't install prerequisites; it just complains if they're not installed.  It's the CPAN client's job to install prerequisites.

Note: [Module::Install](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-Install/lib/Module/Install.pod) has an `auto_install` feature that does this, but the general consensus seems to be that using it is a bad idea.

Comment: If you use Module::Build instead of ExtUtils::MakeMaker, you can use `./Build installdeps`. However, some consider M::B a failed experiment (and I think that includes its maintainer).

Comment: Module::Build is also no longer in core as of 5.22.0

Comment: @ikegami Would you mind sharing some additional links to discussions? https://xdg.me/blog/paying-respect-to-modulebuild/