# How does the key "file" of the structure "provides" work with "META.*" for "CPAN::Meta::Spec"?

Tags: perl, dependencies, dependency-management, cpan, metacpan

I'm trying to [better understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484092/how-to-make-prereqs-of-cpanmetaspec-require-a-distribution-instead-of-a-pa) what [I could use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492053/how-to-manage-dependencies-in-perl-above-package-level-and-without-focussing-on) `CPAN::Meta::Spec` for and came across the following sentence in the [spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Meta::Spec#file1) for the key `file`:

> [...]to a file that contains or generates the package. It may be given as META.yml or META.json to claim a package for indexing without needing a *.pm.

This sentence reads to me like one was able to directly specify some `META.*` within the config using a path to a file instead of a `*.pm`. Hence using the wording `it`, that clearly associates to the formerly mentioned path. Pretty much like in the following example:

```
provides => {
  'Foo::Bar' => {
    file    => 'lib/Foo/Bar.pm',
    version => '0.27_02'
  },
  'Foo::Bar2' => {
    file    => 'lib/Foo/Bar2.yml', <-- META.yml?
  },
  'Foo::Bar3' => {
    file    => 'lib/Foo/Bar3.json', <-- META.json?
    version => '0.3'
  }
```

So, while `Foo/Bar2.pm` and `Foo/Bar3.pm` might exist in the distribution, they are not defined explicitly, but implicitly using the `META.*` files.

1. How does such a `META.*` look like, what does it contain? Only things like `name` and `version`, which is what a native Perl package might provide as well? Or additional things like `license` and `keyword`, maybe everything except dependencies?
2. How do CPAN-clients handle such cases? `META.*` obviously isn't the Perl package itself and I don't see how it's used to generate it. So what gets actually installed in a system in the end? Is there some additional mechanism generating the package somehow?
3. How is providing `META.*` instead of `*.pm` compatible with the key `version` and the following restriction:

> [...]If the package does not have a $VERSION, this field must be omitted.

Does `META.*` count as a package containing `$VERSION` in this case? Or is it expected that somehow the package gets generated in the end and that simply must have `$VERSION` as well and as long as the package isn't generated, the version of `META.*` can simply be used?

Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: Create a chat, and tag me in. I might have an idea for your real question. I just can't get into it right now.

Answer (score 1):

The `provides` metadata is a list of the packages provided by the distribution primarily for use by the PAUSE indexer, but also may be used by analysis tools. If it is present, PAUSE will not inspect your files for packages and their versions but will trust `provides`. For each package in the distribution it must list the file in which the package resides, and the version of the package if it has one. Since this is an "override", it is not required to match reality, but unless you're doing something very strange it should. The ability to set the file to `META.yml` or `META.json` is simply a fallback if you have a package which has no associated file; it is extremely uncommon that you will need to do this, and it places no additional requirement on the `META.json` or `META.yml` except they should exist. As always, in implementation this metadata is always set in `META.json` and `META.yml` included in the distribution.